# Nginx rewrite for a docker app with many redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have very less understanding of reverse proxies. I have a requirement where I need to setup one for two docker apps. Both apps would be exposed using https endpoints.

Whole nginx-config structure is as follows:

App1 :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; 
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certboti
        server_name  <example.com>; 
        #root /var/www/html/dexample.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://10.10.180.2:5004/;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Host     $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded_Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                #proxy_ssl_name          $host;
                #proxy_ssl_server_name   on;
                #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        }
}
```

And above App works fine when accessed externally using https.

Problem is I have only one domain so I'll have to use same domain for App2 ( This is express server based app). For this I just added another server block in same file below above:

```
server {
        listen 3004 ssl;
#        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certboti
        server_name  example.com; #
        #root /var/www/html/example.com;


        location /service/897tfUy {
                proxy_pass https://10.10.180.2:3001/service/897tfUy;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Host     $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               # proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded_Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                #proxy_ssl_name          $host;
                #proxy_ssl_server_name   on;
                #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;


        }

}
```

Problem:
When I access url: https://example.com:3004/service/897tfUy
it redirects to url: https://example.com:3004/login-service with 404 error in browser.

As per developer this page has code that will redirect user to an Identity provider like Azure or Okta or any other for that matter.
IDP will authenticate user using Authorization code flow and after successful authentication send back the response to App2 at redirect url specified at:

https://example.com:3004/Oauthcallback

( Here 2 calls are made - 1. to authorization endpoint as response.redirect and 2. call to token endpoint as request.redirect)

After successfully receiving the Access Token and Refresh Token, App2 will render another page as:

https://example.com/resource (from App2)

I have no idea how to achieve this using nginx reverse configuration.